# Grouping objects by two fields using Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a problem grouping two values with Java 8.

My main problem is about grouping two fields, I group correctly one field called `getNameOfCountryOrRegion()` but now I am interested in `groupingBy` another field that is called `leagueDTO` as well.

```
Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>> result = countryDTOList.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                             FullCalendarDTO::getNameOfCountryOrRegion));
```

And the following class :

```
public class FullCalendarDTO  {
    private long id;
    private TeamDTO localTeam;
    private TeamDTO visitorTeam;
    private LocationDTO location;   
    private String leagueDTO;       
    private String timeStamp;
    private String nameOfCountryOrRegion;
}
```

The result will be grouped by `nameOfCountryOrRegion` and `leagueDTO`.

Comment: What do you mean by *and leagueDTO*? Will it be a nested map? Can you show how the desired output must look like?

Comment: Do you want to get a map whose keys are a combination of both fields? If so then the function passed to `groupingBy()` would have to build and return an appropriate object.

Comment: @user7 I would sense that as `groupingBy` both the attributes. Possibly any other meaning as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to group by using two attributes, your output would be a `Map` with keys as the *first attribute used to group*(`getNameOfCountryOrRegion`) and values as a `Map` again with keys as the *second attribute used to group*(`getLeagueDTO`) and its values as a `List<FullCalendarDTO>` which are grouped based on the keys specified.

This shall look like :

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>>> result = countryDTOList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getNameOfCountryOrRegion,
                Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getLeagueDTO)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Passing a `downstream` collector to `groupingBy` will do the trick:

```
countryDTOList.stream()
              .collect(groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getNameOfCountryOrRegion,
                       groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getLeagueDTO)));
```

The code snippet above will group your `FullCalendarDTO` objects by `nameOfCountryOrRegion` then each group will be grouped by `leagueDTO`.

So the returned collection will look like `Map<String, Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Collectors class groupingBy() method supports an additional Collector as a second argument:

```
public static <T, K, A, D>    Collector<T, ?, Map<K, D>> groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)
```

The above can be written to groupBy() two values

```
Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>> result = countryDTOList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getNameOfCountryOrRegion, Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getLeagueDTO)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the original list to be grouped into Map of Maps.
Below is the code snippet

```
    List<FullCalendarDTO> arrayList = new ArrayList<FullCalendarDTO>();
    arrayList.add(new FullCalendarDTO("US","A"));
    arrayList.add(new FullCalendarDTO("EU","A"));
    arrayList.add(new FullCalendarDTO("EU","A"));
    arrayList.add(new FullCalendarDTO("US","A"));
    arrayList.add(new FullCalendarDTO("US","B"));

    Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>> result = arrayList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getNameOfCountryOrRegion));

    HashMap<String, Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>>> finalOutput = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>>>();
    for (Entry<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>> fullCalendarDTO : result.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, List<FullCalendarDTO>> collect = fullCalendarDTO.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FullCalendarDTO::getLeagueDTO));
        finalOutput.put(fullCalendarDTO.getKey(), collect);
    }

    System.out.println(finalOutput);
```

which Outputs

{EU={A=[EU :: A, EU :: A]}, US={A=[US :: A, US :: A], B=[US :: B]}}

Comment: The correct approach is to use a downstream collector.